# grouping panel dataframe and creating variable

Tags: r

I am working with survey data and I do not manage to do the following exercise. My dataframe looks like this.

```
familyid memberid memberidprev panelid Year
100      1        NA           1       2010
100      2        NA           1       2010
100      2        1            2       2011
100      1        2            2       2011
100      2        2            3       2012
100      1        1            3       2012
100      2        2            4       2013
100      1        1            4       2013
100      1        1            5       2014
100      2        NA           5       2014
100      3        NA           5       2014
100      1        2            6       2015  
100      2        3            6       2015
```

where basically I have family (familyid) and individual (memberid) identifiers, together with an additional variable, i.e. memberidprev, which tells me which was the identifier of the same family member in the previous interview.

What I am not capable of doing is to create a new variable which allows me to have the right identifier for each household member at each point in time. In other words I would like to obtain something like this

```
familyid memberid memberidprev panelid Year    result
100      1        NA           1       2010     1
100      2        NA           1       2010     2
100      2        1            2       2011     1
100      1        2            2       2011     2
100      2        2            3       2012     1
100      1        1            3       2012     2
100      2        2            4       2013     1
100      1        1            4       2013     2
100      1        1            5       2014     2
100      2        NA           5       2014     12
100      3        NA           5       2014     13
100      1        2            6       2015     12
100      2        3            6       2015     13
100      3        1            6       2015     2
```

I would like therefore to create a variable "result" which keeps track of whether there is a "shift" between memberid and memberidprev even for the follow-up period after the shift has occurred, and not only in the period right after the shift occurs.

For instance,in Year=2011, the memberid=2 corresponds to memberid=1 in Year 2010. Therefore my variable result should have result=1 whenever there is member=2 between 2010 and 2014. In 2014 instead, another shift happens, since memberid=2 and memberid=3 present NA in memberidprev, which means they were not present in the previous interview (Year=2013). For this reason I would like my variable result to create new identifiers (12 and 13 respectively) for them.

I hope that I have been clear enough..
Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: Can you explain how you created `result` for first 2-3 rows?

Comment: for the first 2 rows I would like "result" to take the value of memberid, since this is the first interview. For rows 3 and 4 instead I want "result" to take the value of memberidprev, since panelid==2 is the first period in which the shift occurs, as you can notice from the different values taken by memberid and memberidprev. Then I would like to assign the same values taken by "result" in rows 3 and 4 even in the follow-up periods, until a new, potential shift occurs.

Comment: is it more clear now? @RonakShah

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear to me. Some questions which I am confused about. How do you define a "shift" ? What is a "follow-up" period ? Can you explain it based on the example you have shared?

Comment: Dear @RonakShah. First of all, many thanks for your interest. I tried to enrich my post in order to make it clearer. With "shift" I mean whenever memberid and memberidprev do not match. This means that one individual today (identified with memberid) was not identified with the same number in the previous time observation (memberidprev). With follow-up periods I mean all periods after the first shift occurs, and possibly before another one occurring. Let me know If you have other doubts regarding my explanation.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and to add more rows in the example. It definitely helped to make problem statement more clear. I have added an answer below, please check if it work as per your expectation. Moreover, when the "shift" happened I did not understand the logic how identifier was changed from 1, 2 to directly 12, 13. I have just incremented it by 1 showing it as 3, 4 instead of 12, 13. Hopefully, it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this using a `for` loop

```
#Initialize the identifier and result 
df$result <- 0
identifier <- 0

#For every row in df
for (i in  seq_len(nrow(df))) {
    #Check if the shift occurs (NA in current memberidprev)
    if (is.na(df$memberidprev[i])) {
       #Create a new identifier
       identifier = identifier + 1
       df$result[i] <- identifier
    }
   else {
     #If there is no shift get result from previous Year and memberid
     df$result[i] <- df$result[df$memberid == df$memberidprev[i] & 
                              (df$Year[i] - 1) == df$Year]
   }
}

df
#   familyid memberid memberidprev panelid Year result
#1       100        1           NA       1 2010      1
#2       100        2           NA       1 2010      2
#3       100        2            1       2 2011      1
#4       100        1            2       2 2011      2
#5       100        2            2       3 2012      1
#6       100        1            1       3 2012      2
#7       100        2            2       4 2013      1
#8       100        1            1       4 2013      2
#9       100        1            1       5 2014      2
#10      100        2           NA       5 2014      3
#11      100        3           NA       5 2014      4
#12      100        1            2       6 2015      3
#13      100        2            3       6 2015      4
#14      100        3            1       6 2015      2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(familyid = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), memberid = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), memberidprev = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L), panelid = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Year = c(2010L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```